# what is endlessadapter in fragment on rotation best practice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, commonsware-cwac

So im using the endlessadapter from commonsware on a fragment and the issue i have is that every time i rotate while the adapter is waiting to finish loading some data, the cacheInBackground method is called again. The initialization of the adapter is called on the onActivityCreated method from the fragment, so how i can i simply resume the result of the first call of cacheInBackground method?

```
IpdmsEndlessAdapter endAdapt= new IpdmsEndlessAdapter(getActivity(),adapter,R.layout.list_loading_row){


        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws RequestException{
            tempList.clear();
            List<MyProcessDTO> myPRocs;

            myPRocs = new MyprocessesManager(getActivity()).getMyProcessesFromServer(processListPage);

            if(myPRocs!=null){
                tempList.addAll(myPRocs);
            }else
                return false;
            //return true if there's more data do return
            //return false if there was an error or there's no more data
            return myPRocs.size()>=10;


        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onException(View pendingView, Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            GenericMenuAdapter a=(GenericMenuAdapter)getWrappedAdapter();

            for(MyProcessDTO myProcessDTO:tempList){
                a.add(new IpdmsMobileMenuItemListDTO(myProcessDTO.getNrprocesso(), myProcessDTO.getEtapa(), 0, myProcessDTO));
            }
            processListPage++;

        }

    };
    actualListView.setAdapter(endAdapt);
```

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this be a dynamic fragment (i.e., set it up via a `FragmentTransaction`) and call `setRetainInstance(true)` on it somewhere during setup (e.g., `onActivityCreated()`). This will keep the adapter instance between configuration changes.

There may still be some issues with a configuration change while the background thread is doing its work. If you are running into problems even after applying the above recommendations, post a comment on this answer.

Comment: Hi there! Mark! I'm currently calling this fragment with a viewpager, i just did what you said and i've put the setRetainInstance to true on the onActivityCreated method of the fragment, it seems that if i rotate while it's still loading , a new task(from cacheInBackground method) is called. Is there a way to prevent this?, also is it good practice to use setRetainInstance for dealing with threads/asynctasks on fragments or is there a drawback in maintaining the fragment while on rotation?

Comment: @Maxrunner: I'll have to run some experiments to determine the best strategy here. That may take a few days. I have opened a GitHub issue to track this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/issues/9

Comment: @Maxrunner: That being said, `AsyncTask` and retained fragments go together very well.

Comment: Forgot to ask, if i put setRetainInstance to true, what fragment lify cicle methods are ignored??i know that onCreate will not be called, but what about onCreateView and onSaveInstanceState?are they called?

Comment: @Maxrunner: `onCreateView()` is still called. Off the top of my head, I do not know if `onSaveInstanceState()` is called -- you'd have to check the docs or run a test.

Comment: Ok as a last question :D, do you have an example of how to deal with async tasks and fragments/rotation, i'm converting some code from previous android version with compatibility lib and still have some doubts on how to approach it.

Comment: @Maxrunner: Nothing small at the moment, sorry.